# Applications for bug detections - training for manual tester

Tags: testing, manual-testing

Hello dear Stackoverflow community,

I want to challenge myself with testing and bug detection. I am looking for opportunities to get some practice. Tutorials and blogs are great source of knowledge but I think that practice gives far more awareness and experience than just watching other testers. I have tried multiple questions for both Google and Stackoverflow to find any applications, but with no results by now.

**My question is: does any of you know any applications, both executable on local device or accessible via Web, where bugs are intentional so they to be detected for practice?** 
It would be great if there would be any list of bugs for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked on two websites long back for practicing my Manual Testing skills, they are still working. Hope this helps.

```
https://asta.pgs-soft.com/
http://www.mrbuggy.pi/
```

Comment: thank you Alapan. Only second link should be ".pl" instead of ".eu" :) This is what I was looking for :)